# Force PHP Script Connections use IPV4 instead of IPV6

Tags: php, cpanel

I started using ipv6 in my server but I ran in some issues, for example to send a notification to Android and iOS, it wasn't deliverying, so I solved the android notification issue by adding

> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);

PHP is making all output connections (like curl, stream_context, fwrite to URL)  using IPV6 , instead of IPV4 , is there a global way (in script) to define php to only use IPV4 in those requests instead of IPV6 ? My server has both IPV4 and IPV6 enabled.
I don't  want to disable IPV6 because some people that access my site are IPV6 only users.

Answer (score 1):

You should try:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
```

Comment: You can read about it here: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE.html

Comment: This only helps for CURL (and also this has to be applied everytime I start a cURL), not for all other commands, like the ones I mentioned, (stream_context, fwrite, file_get_contents (when for url) )

Comment: Oh snap, I just realized that you mentioned that same call in your question :( In this case you should probably try: 
$opts = array(
    'socket' => array(
        'bindto' => '0:0',
    ),
);

Comment: THANKS: helped me in resolving problem with: curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, 'XX.XX.XX.XX');